# Problem with inotify-wait as daemon

Tags: bash, scripting, inotify

I have been running inotify-wait on my ftp server in byobu to monitor a folder, move data, and send email notifications for a few months without problems. Since I started this I have added 3 more folders that I monitor and I would like to start running inotify-wait as a daemon instead of in byobu sessions. I modified my script to be easier to only require a single variable to be changed and to run as a daemon. Unfortunately it now does nothing. I was hoping someone with some experience could take a look and tell me where Ive gone wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=testuser
dir=/ftp/"$user"/upload/
log=/ftp/"$user"/log/"$user.log"
archive=/ftp/"$user"/archive/
target=/ftp/FTPDATA/"$user"/

inotifywait -q\
-d "$dir" \
-o "$log" \
-e close_write --format %f . | while IFS= read -r file; do
cp -p "$file" "$target"
/scripts/"$user-notify.sh"
mv "$file" "$archive""$(date +%F-%T)"
done
```

Comment: "Does nothing" is a bit difficult to debug. Have you tried `set -o errexit`? Have you tried printing a string when you enter the loop? Have you tried `touch`ing a file in the directory and seeing if the loop progresses? How are you running this as a daemon? Are you sure `inotifywait` is on the `PATH` in the context you're running it?

Comment: I think you are correct that it the -d does not accept the "$dir" like the -m does in my previous script. I have been using touch to create files in the $dir and inotifywait does not appear to recognize the change.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `inotifywait` are you using? According to [this `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) `-d` specifies that you want to run it as a daemon, but it doesn't take an argument value (`"$dir"`). Also with `-o "$log"` it will be saving output to the log file and not sending it to standard output. Make sure you have a working `inotifywait` command before continuing with the script - ideally add a [test](https://github.com/kward/shunit2) which watches some files in a temporary directory (or re-implement in a better language like Java, Python or Ruby).